# Scss box-shadow is deprecated and will be removed - How to work around

Tags: sass, bourbon

I am trying to use the following include in my style.scss file:

```
@include box-shadow(red 2px 2px 10px);
```

However i get a an error of:

> WARNING: box-shadow is deprecated and will be removed in the next
>   major version release

I've tried to google this, but i am not sure what i use instead, is there another mixin i can manually make or use? I looked on the Bourbon website in their docs but all i found was:

> Deprecation Warning: The box-shadow mixin has been deprecated. Use the
>   official spec.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon/issues/156) is the discussion within Bourbon

> Box-shadow mixin should be deprecated based on current implementation of the property in browsers.

so you should use:

```
box-shadow: red 2px 2px 10px;
```

instead of:

```
@include box-shadow(red 2px 2px 10px);
```